# Install wc3 markup validator locally

Tags: 13.10, html, apache2.4

How to install and use w3c markup validator on Ubuntu 13.10 locally? I know I can install it by installing following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2   
sudo apt-get install w3c-markup-validator
```

but how do I configure it to use it same way as [on-line version](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) (that is by web browser), but locally?

Comment: Its uses CGI to work, and is probably designed for a webserver - the script on ubuntu seems to be located at `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/w3c-markup-validator/check`. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16673201/2943276

Comment: @Rafal : if you find a way to use the validator offline, can you reply with detailed steps please, I was also looking for that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good news! So if you have apache2 already installed, you install W3C Validator and Perl:

```
sudo apt-get install w3c-markup-validator libapache2-mod-perl2
```

The issue is that the w3c-markup-validator package hasn't been updated to install properly on 13.10+ (I'm on 14.04). To fix it manually:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/w3c/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/w3c-markup-validator.conf
```

I then had an issue where `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` didn't have the correct permissions. This is due to a problem in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf` where it will only give the correct permission if the module is being loaded. It appears this version of perl isn't listed in the IfModule statement. To fix this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

You want it to look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_perl.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </IfDefine>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Once you're done with these steps you have to symlink validator's html directory to /var/www/html:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/w3c-markup-validator/html /var/www/html/w3c-validator
```

Once the file is linked and the changes are in place, all you have to do is restart the Apache server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Check that it's all working

```
http://localhost/w3c-validator
```

CSS might be missing from validator page in the browser, but validation should work well.

Comment: try `sudo xdg-open http://localhost/w3c-validator` or to change httpd.conf's permission with `sudo chown $USER:$USER /etc/w3c/httpd.conf` and `sudo chmod 777 /etc/w3c/httpd.conf`.

Comment: I gave that a try and it didn't work. I'm pretty sure the problem is in `/etc/w3c/httpd.conf` and how it uses mod_rewrite to link to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/w3c-markup-validator/check`. Possibly an Apache rule about running code perl that's not in the docroot...

Comment: /etc/w3c/validator.conf might also need checking. E.g. there might be a validator.conf.dpkg-dist that is different.

Answer (score 1):

After applying @Skarard's answer the W3CValidator showed up but the check didn't work. There were errors in /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
  AH01337: Could not parse expr "$QUERY_STRING = /(^|[;&])debug(=[^0]?)?(\\b|$)/" in /usr/share/w3c-markup-validator/html/header.html: Parse error near '$'
  AH01337: Could not parse expr "$includeJS = 1" in /usr/share/w3c-markup-validator/html/header.html: Parse error near '$'
  AH01337: Could not parse expr "$debug = 1" in /usr/share/w3c-markup-validator/html/header.html: Parse error near '$'
  AH01337: Could not parse expr "$feeds = 1" in /usr/share/w3c-markup-validator/html/header.html: Parse error near '$'
```

So I found out that the validator.conf file was pointing to a wrong schema location. There was a left over validator.conf.dpkg-dist

```
/etc/w3c# diff validator.conf validator.conf.dpkg-dist 
42c42
<     Library = /usr/share/xml/xhtml/schema/dtd
---
>     Library = /usr/share/xml/w3c-sgml-lib/schema/dtd
57c57
< Allow Private IPs = yes
---
> Allow Private IPs = no
75c75
<   Allow = http
---
>   Allow = data,ftp,http,https
118,123d117
< 
< #
< # Source for the "Tip of The Day" blurbs.
< <Tips>
<   Include tips.cfg
< </Tips>
```

I moved the validator.conf.dkpk-dist to validator.conf and restarted apache.
The error messages in /var/log/apache2/error.log were still there.

Apache 2.4 being in use seemed to be the reason as outlined in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878076/how-does-expression-work-in-apache-2-4) so i had to add

```
SSILegacyExprParser On
```

to the w3c-markup-validator.conf file.