# dpkg: error processing package w3c-markup-validator

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, dpkg, error-handling

I have installed w3c-markup-validator on Ubuntu 14.04 with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install w3c-markup-validator
```

After that, each time I run `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get install` I get following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package w3c-markup-validator
Errors were encountered while processing:
    w3c-markup-validator
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Initially, I thought that it had something to do with the fact that there were some issues with `w3c-markup-validator` related to newer Apache version, but even after fixing those issues as stated in [Install wc3 markup validator locally](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471523/install-wc3-markup-validator-locally), this error message still occurs every time I use `apt-get`.

Is there any way to supress this one error message? Optionally, what might be cause of this error message?

Answer (score 1):

(I wanted to just add a comment to Rho's answer, but I am new here so)
I believe that purging will do the work.
If you:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge w3c-markup-validator
```

Or, in case it doesn't work:

```
sudo dpkg --purge w3c-markup-validator
```

Then follow Rho's sequence, it will be fixed.

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a 

 sudo apt-get install -f 

 sudo apt-get update 

 sudo apt-get install -f
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that after the install you got your package system corrupted. In order to solve it please try this out in a terminal:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

`sudo apt-get install -f`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -f`

That should fix your package system and let you use apt-get normally again. Cheers! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, after running those commands, this error still shows up.

Comment: could you please post the output of the first one?